# How do you loop if statements if they come out false?

Tags: c

I’ve just starting coding in C and thought I would try my hand at something I thought would be simple. I got it working and now I want it to loop if it comes out false so I can input a number again. Help?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("Enter The Passcode: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if (a != 625){
        printf("Correct Passcode");
    }
   else if (a == 625){
        printf("Incorrect Passcode");
}
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Start by writing a loop. Did you try searching here for *c loop for user input*?

Comment: `if (a == 625)` is redundant because when it comes to that clause it must be equal to 625, that's what "else" means. And don't use brackets in return, it's not a function

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Sorry, but this question is likely to be closed as being too trivial. You should look into [while loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_while_loop.htm) and a good book on learning C like [Learn C The Hard Way](https://learncodethehardway.org/c/). Honestly if you're just learning how to program, C might not be a good choice. It's quite complicated and it's better to learn the basics in a high level language like [Ruby](http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0) first.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the answers. I’ll search for c loop for user input. Okay, I understand you guys closing it. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @NoiDea I hope you will find my solution useful

Answer (score 0):

To get you pointed in the right direction, you'd use a `while` loop here. It's not fundamentally different to have a boolean expression claiming that something's *not* the case than to have one claiming that it's true. `1 != 2`, for example, is perfectly true (because 1 actually *doesn't* equal 2). It sounds slightly odd, but think about why this statement is true and I think this'll clarify the problem.

One quick point. I know that this was mentioned in comments, but in this case `else if (a == 625)` is redundant because `a` couldn't possibly be anything *but* 625 here. Also, I assume that you reversed your `if` statements because the way you wrote this literally any number *other* than 625 is the correct password (look closely at your `if` statements to see why this is the case).

With that said, here's an example that may help you:

```
int a = // Read integer from console;

// This will happen if, and only if, a is something other than 625
// This'll keep prompting them until they enter 625
while (a != 625) {
   printf("Incorrect password. Please enter the correct password.");
   a = // Read integer from console
}

// If we got past the loop, we know that they must have entered a correct password
printf("Correct password");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use loop for this purpose like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=0; //some random
    printf("Enter The Passcode: ");


while(a!=625){
     scanf("%d", &a);
     if (a != 625){
        printf("Correct Passcode");
        break; // you found correct
     }
     else if (a == 625){
        printf("Incorrect Passcode");
      }

   }
    return(0);
}
```